# how do I get the final result of a check [PYTHON]

Tags: python, selenium

I'm doing an automation using selenium e python that has to check if a certain text is present on the page.
So I have to check if 4 words are present.
Example text: "Any text I'm using for testing".

The selenium check to see if it is present or not, I managed to do it. But I was unable to reach a final result to store and then show it to the user.
When I use "if" and "else". It checks only the first, without checking the rest.

Example:

```
if "text" in "Any text I'm using as a test":
return 'text is present'
else:
return ''

if "any" in "Any text I'm using as a test":
return 'any is present'
else:
return ''

if "using" in "Any text I'm using as a test":
return 'using is present'
else:
return ''
```

What I want is to check all "if and else" before giving the result. After checking all, I want you to give me an answer, example:
"Are present: text and any".

To tell you the truth, I don't even know if this has to do with "if".

sorry for my english, I put it in the translator

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get_present_text(my_text_to_be_checked: str, bits_to_check_for: list):
    present_bits = [bit for bit in bits_to_check_for if bit.lower() in my_text_to_be_checked.lower()]

    return present_bits


print("Are present:", " and ".join(get_present_text("Hello World!", ["Hello", "Space", "!"])))
> Are present: Hello and !
```